# File upload dialog not shown

Tags: jquery, upload, internet-explorer-9

I am facing a problem when uploading a file. When I click on the ClickMe button, the dialog confirm is showing. When I click the OK button, the upload file dialog is not shown. If I run the code in the console, the upload file dialog is shown. Here is my source code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUpload() {
   $("#tpl_file").click();
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#verify_dialog").dialog({
        "autoOpen": false,
        "modal": true,
        "buttons": [{
            "id":"btn_okdialog",
            "text": "yes",
            "click": function() {
                showUpload();
            }
          },
          {
            "id":"btn_cancedialog",
            "text": "no",
            "click": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          }
        ]
    });
    $("#ClickMe").button();
    $("#ClickMe").click(function(){
        $("#verify_dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button title="ClickMe" id="ClickMe">ClickMe</button>
<input type="file" name="tpl_file" id="tpl_file">
<div id="verify_dialog" style="display:none;" title="verify_dialog">
    <div id="message">are you sure?</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help identify the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your function showUpload() is triggered, but the code in it does not work:

```
$("#tpl_file").click();
```

I'm not sure about what you want to do, if you want to trigger a click event, you should use:

```
$("#tpl_file").trigger('click');
```

Comment: you need to build a form-tag around your input field, <form id=yourformid action="yourtargetaddress"><input..></form>, take a look at how to build html forms here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp Then you need to add a click function to your showUpload() you want to start your upload right? Then you can say $(#yourformid).submit(); Hope this leads you to a better way and to a solution :)